# How do I programmatically find SharingRules for standard Objects?

Tags: soql, sharing, standard-objects

Update:

[image]

[image]

I meant to say how to find using SOQL, APEX or REST API.

Is there a way to find sharing model for the standard objects using SOQL/REST/SOAP? like what are the sharing settings for opportunity or account object? etc..

Comment: I am pretty sure you know how to reach Setup - Security Controls - Sharing Setting .....   are you trying to refer something else?

Comment: updated my question.

Comment: Hey @NickKahn, did you find a solution for this?

Comment: @RogerioHonorio nope I did not, but I heard you can do using metadata api but I haven't tried

Comment: Thank you, it seems like we can as you said using Metadata Api. 
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_sharingsettings.htm?search_text=Sharing

Answer (score 1):

All sharing Settings should be in the same place **Setup - Security Controls - Sharing Setting** in classic, **Setup - Security - Sharing Setting** in Lightning or just searching for Sharing Setting in the setup quick find.

Comment: Updated my question.

Answer (score 0):

For the Standard object, you can use Organization object to achieve this, query like

```
Organization org = [Select Id, DefaultAccountAccess, DefaultContactAccess, DefaultLeadAccess, DefaultOpportunityAccess from Organization];

System.debug(org);
```

Verified that it does return values but with different verbiage:

Private ==> none;

Public Read/Write ==> Edit;

Public Read Only ==> Read;

Controlled by Parent ==> ControlledByParent;

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_organization.htm

Comment: i don't think that organization pulls from the OWD sharing model, for an example, my Opportunity is public read only and when I run the above query it gets me `edit` for the opportunity, does not seems correct. any thoughts?

Comment: It does return correct value - but with different verbiage..Private = none;  Public Read/Write = Edit; Public Read Only = Read...etc

Comment: I have updated my question and add the screen shot, please have a look.

Answer (score 0):

First connect SFDX to salesforce org

Loop on each object (custom or standard)
run: sfdx force:source:retrieve -m CustomObject:Your_Custom_Object__c

The Meta xml file retrieved will contain visibility & sharing model tags (pub/priv/rw)
e.g. 
Private
Public

You can parse for this and get it for the org and all objs